# What does the double percentage sign (%%) mean?

Tags: r

What is the double percent (`%%`) used for in R?

From using it, it looks as if it divides the number in front by the number in back of it as many times as it can and returns the left over value.  Is that correct?

Out of curiosity, when would this be useful?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The "Arithmetic operators" help page (which you can get to via `?"%%"`) says

> ‘`%%`’ indicates ‘x mod y’

which is only helpful if you've done enough programming to know that this is referring to the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), i.e. integer-divide `x` by `y` and return the remainder. This is useful in many, many, many applications. For example (from @GavinSimpson in comments), `%%` is useful if you are running a loop and want to print some kind of progress indicator to the screen every nth iteration (e.g. use `if (i %% 10 == 0) { #do something}` to do something every 10th iteration).

Since `%%` also works for floating-point numbers in R, I've just dug up an example where `if (any(wts %% 1 != 0))` is used to test where any of the `wts` values are non-integer.

Comment: Great, thanks for the reply.  I looked at the ?"%%", but didn't understand what the 'x mod y' meant.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem you are encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept it ...  Also, for future reference, it's useful to state in your question what you've already tried (e.g. "I looked at `?"**"` and I see it says 'x mod y' but I don't know what that means") so that people can give you the most useful answer

Comment: What about `%>%`? I've seen that used in a few examples, but I'm not sure what it does (that's how I arrived here).

Comment: it's hard to search for, but look at the `magrittr` package.

Comment: Another example of usage of `%%` is in printing a statistic or such like to the screen every nth iteration. For example you could use `if (i %% 10 != 0) { #do something}` to do something every 10th iteration.

Comment: @TravisHeeter `%>%` was also used by the `pipeR` package. (Finally `pipeR` switched to `%>>%` to avoid conflicts with the `magrittr` package)

Comment: Just to add to @BenBolker's comment, it's defined by the package `magrittr` [(CRAN)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/index.html) and is heavily used by `dplyr` [(CRAN)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html).

Comment: @GavinSimpson you don't want the ! in that line, you want another =
i.e. every 10th iteration the remainder (of 10/10 or 20/10) SHOULD be 0

Comment: @dez93_2000 Yup; silly typo that Ben and I overlooked

Comment: You should ask a new question like "what is %>%?" as a new question not in a comment.

Comment: I read through these examples and did some experimenting. Will someone explain why 90%%360 is 90 and not 0 if the remainder of 360/90 is 0 since 90 goes into 360 4 times. also why is -90%%360 = 270?

Comment: The `%%` operator is not commutative (i.e. `a %% b != b %%a`). `360 %% 90` is 0 (the remainder of 360/90 is 0); `90 %% 360` is 90 (the remainder of 90/360 is 90). `-90 %% 360` is a little trickier to explain, but the result of `a %% b` is always between 0 (inclusive) and b (exclusive). (Taking the modulus is sometimes called "clock arithmetic", if that helps ...)

Answer (score 13):

The result of the %% operator is the REMAINDER of a division,

Eg. 75%%4 = 3

I noticed if the *dividend* is lower than the *divisor*, then R returns the same *dividend* value.

Eg. 4%%75 = 4

Cheers

[image: division parts]

Answer (score 3):

`%%` in R return remainder
for example:

```
s=c(1,8,10,4,6)
d=c(3,5,8,9,2)
x=s%%d
x
[1] 1 3 2 4 0
```