# In R, how does double percent work when used on a matrix?

Tags: r, syntax

```
    a <- data.frame(1:50)
    a %% 10==0
```

It returns TRUE for row numbers in increments of 10, starting at 0.

```
    a %% 10==2
```

This does the same thing, but starting at 2.

How does this syntax work? I know what %% is as an operator but I don't understand what's happening in this scenario.

Comment: You are checking if `a` mod `10` is equal to zero, and if `a` mod `10` is equal to 2.  The result is yes or no.  Not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257819

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Hope I haven't over explained this and interpreted what you're asking correctly:)

As you've said, you know that `%%` is the modulus operator. So

```
a <- data.frame(1:50)
a %% 10
```

returns 'x mod 10' for each item in the frame (or 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 etc etc)

The two examples you've given are like 'shorthand' for `if` statements. In pseudo code:

```
for n = 1 to length of a
    if a[n] %% 10 equals zero 
      return true
    else 
      return false
```

So `a %% 10 == 0` is "Does the element mod 10 equal zero" and `a %% 10 == 2` is "Does the element mod 10 equal two" applied to each element

And the result is matrix of logicals (booleans).

Comment: I understand it now. I was looking at the syntax from the completely wrong perspective. Thank you.