# How to use/understand "%%"

Tags: r

Can anyone tell me what this code means --> train = (year%%2 == 0). I have set it up with a binary variable, and it looks to me that it changes from "TRUE" to "FALSE" (vice versa) everytime "year" increases with 1

Comment: This is the modulo operator. Easy to google.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257819/what-does-the-double-percentage-sign-mean

Comment: @maarvd I have read that one, but it doesn't make sense. According to him it would mean that for every 2nd iteration it would do something, but in my data its not the case :(

Comment: @Vincent Thanks, now it makes sense to me!